# Is there a way to update automatically a worksheet based on a link which provided a file for download

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have created a web app which allows the user to download a csv file just by copying the link into a browser. Afterwards the user can open this file with excel.

Because the csv file might change several times a day , I don't want the user to constantly download and open the file. What I want is to automate this process. 
Excel have a nice feature which is called web query.This feature allow you to import the contents of a webpage in excel,e.g : html tables. Once you import this data, to update it you just have to click on the button "refresh all". In my case, I can't do that because my file is not printed in the html page, it is just available for download.

The only way I found is to print my csv file in the webpage and use the web query feature that I described above. I'm just wondering if there is another way other than to print every data on the webpage.

Finally , I'm not sure if here is the correct place to ask this question. But I'm taking my chance based on this this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The correct way is to do this with a web query as you've already discovered. It isn't clear why you want to have an app that creates a CSV when you don't need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess i will print every data on the webpage and use the web query feature. I created the app this way because of the specs, Afterwards I've noticed that the file might change a several times a day. Because of that I decided to search a way which will facilitate the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may have a reason for creating an app to do this, it's difficult to be certain. However, unless you do have a special reason  you haven't told us about, you can achieve what you're asking using built-in browser behaviour that occurs automatically when clicking a link.

For example, you might have the following link in your web page:

```
<a href="myfile.csv">myfile.csv</a>
```

When a user clicks this link, the user's browser will offer to open the file using the program that's associated with the .csv file extension on the user's machine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I am searching for. I want the user to be able to import the link in excel. I don't want him to download a file  using the browser. what i'm searching for is exactly what excel provide   when you click on the tab data>From web. This solution offer you the possibility to update the data imported with just a button "refresh all". but the problem is to be able to import data that way your html page must display an htm table( with the table tags).